# Centered and fixed header

Tags: html, css, positioning

I am working on my portfolio: [www.bbellmedia.com/mywork](http://www.bbellmedia.com/mywork)

I want the text 'Bryan Bell' to be centered how it is, but also be fixed when a user scrolls.

What is the best way of achieving this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you don't include your CSS in the question (instead of a link), this will never help anyone else.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I realize that now, it was a n00b mistake. I will add it.

Comment: @wesleymurch well I was going to add the CSS for others to see, but you closed it :[

Comment: nice try, but you can still edit the question to add the CSS. It's the 'edit' link, right under the tags.  If you edit it, flag the question (or post a comment), and I'll see it and will re-open it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#header {
  position:fixed;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want the image does not over your heading, use this

```
.header {
   ....
   position: fixed;
   top: 0px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: black;
   z-index: 300;
}

.app1{
   margin-top: 184px;
}
```

Comment: so this would make it go under the header and not on top?

Answer (score 0):

Hey now used to this **css** **style-sheet**

**`.header`** to give `position fixed` and now give to `left 0` `right 0` `top 0` and give `z-index maximum`

```
.header {
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
```